# GH Pages not showing Images

Tags: image, github-pages

guys. I have seen already a few other topics about it but I'm still facing troubles concerning making the images appear on my GH Pages. Can someone take a look and help?

[GH Page Here](https://ninacressoni.github.io/StarWars-Shop/)

If you go in Products or Home you will see that the images aren't appearing.
I've tried changing the path but still not figured out completely.

(you can see every photo is with a different path because I was trying to see which one fits)

The path to the images is in the [Data.js](https://github.com/ninacressoni/StarWars-Shop/blob/master/src/components/Data.js) file.

Comment: Currently, that page doesn't even load because you have a ` "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.apply') `. Try doing some if-else conditional error checking on the variable "t"

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Where are you seeing this message? Here the page is loading.

Comment: if you hit ctrl+shift+c (dev tools), you can see the error in console. And on my end, ur GH Page link does not load (most likely due to that error)